# Android key character map and triggering MENU, HOME, BACK

Tags: android, unicode, keyboard

I have a requirement to use hardcoded key combos like ctrl-shift-[, ctrl-shift], etc to globally trigger MENU, HOME, and BACK key functionality from a usb attached keyboard.

I've been directed to do this using key character maps.  In .kcm files, you can use MENU, HOME and BACK as keywords, but only in a "fallback" clause.  Otherwise, you seem to be stuck with using ascii or hex Unicode characters.

I've searched dozens of places including http://www.unicode.org/charts/ but frankly, the number of Unicode characters is huge and I'm afraid I've missed them.

Is anyone aware of the magic numbers?

Also, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

cben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that using fallback is sufficient.  This avoids the need for using Unicode and lets you use the keywords MENU, HOME, and BACK as noted above.  I think the real issue may have been an error in the .kcm file when I was testing that was preventing fallback from working.

Bottom line:  use validatekeymaps tool manually.  Your compile may not be calling it.

Comment: Can you please provide binary validatekeymaps for linux64bit ?